# How to do simultaneous experiments (simulations) in anylogic?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am trying to simulate a flow shop in anylogic, considering the possibility of a machine break down. When a machine breakdown happens (activated by an event with a probability), I would like to run two parallel simulations: one that considers the fixing time of the machine and production until the end of the day and another that considers that the machine will be broken until the next production day. Afterwords, I would like to compare the values (and calculate the effect of both options). Is it possible to be done in anylogic?

Comment: use the compare runs experiment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Felipe's comment that compare runs will be useful.  One thing to consider based on the wording of your question is that you will likely want 2 full runs.  You said when the machine breaks down, you would like to run two parallel simulations.  However, just run two parallel simulations from the start.  You can put machine break downs on a dedicated random number stream, if you really want to isolate that and make sure the two runs have identical initial break downs.

Another approach would be to develop this model as an agent, and then have two agents on main.  This way, you can watch the animation of the two systems in parallel.  This is not as good for heavy analysis if you have alot of metrics to analyze, but it is nice for simple systems where stakeholders need to see things running side by side.  You could use a parameter to pass into your agent to indicate that one of them takes until the end of the day and the other until the next production day.